# java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError even when $JAVA_HOME is correct

Tags: java

main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/mje/runjobj/Main has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 58.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Specs

~ % java -version
java version "1.8.0_261"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_261-b12)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.261-b12, mixed mode)

~ % javac -version
javac 1.8.0_261

~ % echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_261.jdk/Contents/Home

Comment: Any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This website explains how to change the JRE and compiler of your project. https://www.baeldung.com/java-lang-unsupportedclassversion.  For me changing the JRE and compiler to earlier versions of java fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME isn't used by java itself, it's sometimes used by apps that use java, like maven or gradle or your IDE (but they tend to have more robust ways of finding where java hangs out).

class file version 58 is what javac14 produces.

It is **impossible** for a `javac` that reports v1.8.0 when you run `javac -version`, to produce this class file. If you got this class file from someone else, ask them recompile on java8 (or use `-release 8` when compiling it), or download and install adoptOpenJDK 14.

If you produced this yourself, whatever process produced it was not using the `javac` that responded with `1.8.0` when you ran it. You'd have to explain what ran it (maven? eclipse? intellij? gradle?) for more help.